# keeping socket.io connection open in iOS Background (non app store apps)

Tags: ios

I am developing enterprise app for iOS, this app will not go into the app store. So is there way for me to keep an socket.io(web socket) connection open with the server if the user sends app to background.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Same question here.. haven't found a way yet.. have you?

Comment: Also, is there a solution if it's an app that goes to the App Store?